# Make excel 2007 default to open files in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have Excel 2007, 2010 and 2013 installed in my single PC. Now when I try to open any excel files, by default this open in Excel 2013. 
Now I need to changed this into Excel 2007 open when I click any Excel files.

I have tried options likes: 
1. /unregserver and /regserver 
2. follow this step  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/excel/thread/71ab93b0-1639-49ab-af25-6ba61993d864/

but no luck.

Comment: Which operating system are you using. Windows 7?

Comment: hi dave, I am using windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Right click the excel file, select "open with: Choose default program", then click "browse" and search for the excel 2007 exe file. select it and make sure the radio button always use this program at the bottom of menu.

Comment: I tried initially but noluck, then I tried other options like unregserver and regserver